# 'Unexpected Token Function' Azure Node.js App Service async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am having an issue deploying a node.js application to the Azure App Service. I am getting an `Unexpected token function` on an async in one of the node_modules.

I updated my Azure App Service Node version to `v12.13.0`. In the image, I run `node -v` to confirm. This should then be able to run `Async / await` functions. I can create a `test.js` file with async functions and run it in the console to confirm and it works. However, when I go to run the app, it throws an error from a [node_module](https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support) import that uses an async function on [Line 20](https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support/blob/master/lib/interceptors/request.mjs). [This process is outlined in the annotated picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnBL.png), showing the preview editor of the azure app service.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a specific test code file `test.js`?

Comment: Under windows, the node project has many problems, so it is recommended that you can deploy under linux and continue to try. After my test, the github source code you provided is also not executable under Windows, but normal under Linux.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, thats good to know. The test.js code is in the annotated picture I linked. I started up an linux app service today and put my code on it, but that has been giving me different errors. Been tricky to debug it since for the Linux server the the Kudu tools has limited functionality and App Service editor (Preview) is not available. Currently my log stream is saying " 2020-08 /opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 51: /opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory
2020-08 ERROR - Container for site" Can't really say if the async functions are working until i get past it.

Comment: Can you run successfully in local?

Comment: I want know which way you use to deploy your webapp?

Comment: I suggest you can upload your code into github, then 
use [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment).  The way you use can avoid a lot of strange errors.

Comment: If my suggestion works for you, please let me know. ^-^

Comment: Yup it runs locally, it also runs fine on an IBM Cloud foundry App without issue. This problem is just on Azure it seems. Also, I have it on a Github Repo and a 'Github actions' configured for CD, and it runs successfully

Comment: If you can deploy your webapp and run successfully by continuous deployment, can I post my answer to advice more forum user to use this way to solve the issue when they encounter the same problem.